# How to clear all filters before saving and closing

Tags: excel

I have macros sorting a table for general use by several other managers.
*I* know that I have to clear the filters before saving or I get the error message, "Removed Records: Rich Autofilter from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (Table)". But the other managers don't. Is there a way to make it so the filters clear automatically, like when the save button is used? I was thinking maybe I could create a save button that would run a macro, but that's still putting a lot of faith in my co-managers who don't use excel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe try putting your code to clear the filter in the `Workbook.BeforeSave()` event?